# Converting a list to np array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, numpy-ndarray

Im building a image classification model but first i need to read the images used for training and i have 105,392 images, so i read the local images i have downloaded with cv2.imread_grayscale and resized the image to 100x100

```
train_images = []
img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,str(train_data.filename[idx])), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(img_size,img_size))
train_images.append(new_array)
```

then i add the image data into a list then converted them into nparray and tried to flatten them to 1 dimension so i can save into a text file for easier processing

```
ndarray = np.array(train_images)
ndarray2 = np.ndarray(ndarray)
flattenarray = ndarray2.flatten(order='C')
flattenarray.tofile('train_images_bitmap.txt')
```

but im getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "comp2.py", line 36, in <module>
ndarray2 = np.ndarray(ndarray)
ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 105392
```

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: currently i will have to wait ~10mins each time i need to make a test in the training model, im thinking that i can export the greyscaled, resized image's data into a txt file so i will only need to read that file whenever i run the training model

Comment: Use `np.array` to make array. `np.ndarray` is a low level constructor that we rarely use, and requires more care with its inputs.  Did you look up the `ndarray` docs?

Comment: Actually yes but i dont understand them, i looked up the internet and saw someone did what i needed with ndarray, just that i think they have much lesser dimensions so its successful. but i couldnt get it to work, so i came asking

Comment: `np.ndarray` has `shape` as the first argument. And that's why the error. Read [here](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

Comment: Also what are you trying to achieve from the line in error?

Answer (score 0):

Your array of ndarray has shape of (105392,100,100) to flatten this array.

```
flatten_array = ndarray.reshape(1,105392*100*100)
```